# Bounty Offered Just to Give Reputation to a Specific User...How to Flag a Bounty?

Tags: support, flags, bounty

There's currently an open bounty on a question.  The question was both asked and answered by the same person in a matter of a few hours.  It appears about 2 weeks after the answer was posted, a bounty was placed on this question by another user for this reason "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."  The user offering the bounty has a default user name and hardly any reputation.  Plus neither the question or the answer is exemplary in any way.  This seems to me like the user who asked/answered the question has an alternate account and is trying to bolster his reputation via some odd means.

Anyway, my question is what should be done in the situation of a poor bounty?  There's no way to flag the bounty itself and flagging the question or the answer doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: Note that giving a bounty to a sock puppet isn't creating reputation inappropriately, it's just moving it, but it is still prohibited.

Comment: Have the accounts since been merged? All I see is the question, answer and bounty from the same account.

Comment: It is also possible that this is the account of another person that the bounty awarder knows and is trying to encourage to participate. That isn't really any better, of course.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> There's no way to flag the bounty itself and flagging the question or the answer doesn't seem appropriate.

Why not?  That's *exactly* what you should do.  Flag the post and explain the situation to a mod.

Comment: Flagging the question or the answer seems to imply that there's a problem with the question or a problem with the answer.  But I suppose with an explanation it wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: @danjuggler But there *is* a problem with the question (or at least you think there is) in that you think the author is using it to abuse sock puppets.

Comment: It's more important to get the moderator's attention, even if you aren't flagging the exact right thing -- that's why you have a text field to explain your flag.  In this case, the mod will surely look at the question as part of their investigation, so it's close enough anyway.

Comment: @Servy I'm a bit confused how that'd be abusing though. I mean he's basically transferring the rep he honestly earned on one account to another... but he could've earned the rep on that account in the first place! Seems like a silly undertaking to me. Or is it about bolstering a second account so that one can be used for some things?

Comment: There are lots of possibilities.  You can give a bounty to yourself to feature your questions without costing yourself rep, moving rep from one account to another can give that other account added privileges, giving you the ability to get around rate limiting, for example, double the number of votes, close votes, reviews, questions, etc. you have each day (one set for each account), it's sometimes done to move rep earned illegitimately onto another account, in the hopes that a mod won't notice, thus subverting the rep reversal, etc.